# What determines the ^ version operator for dependencies in package.json when installing a package?

Tags: npm, package.json

I noticed in my package.json that some versions have the `^` operator in the dependency version such as:

`"prettier": "^2.2.1",`

But then some packages do not use this operator such as:

`"typescript": "4.1.3"`

I know the meaning of the operator but I installed both of these packages via `npm install -D <package>` and did not modify package.json myself so how was the inclusion of this operator determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm's [save-prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#save-prefix) setting affects which prefix is set in `package.json` when running `npm install -D <package>` - by default it's set to a caret (`^`).

So yes it's odd some packages have been prefixed with `^` whilst others haven't.

Perhaps via the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-config) command you inadvertently ran `npm config set save-prefix=''` (i.e. you set it to nothing).

If you run `npm config get save-prefix` and it doesn't print `^`, then you need to run `npm config delete save-prefix` to revert to the default `^`